# How to open popup using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angularjs, whenever i click on "login/signup" button then popup is showing,Now i want if i click on "upload resume"(another file) then same popup should appear

Here is my code which is working fine(file location is /var/www/html/views/common)

```
<header id="top" ng-controller="headerCtrl" roller class="navbar js-navbar-affix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-right">
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg hoj-blue-light login-reg-btn bold"
                                data-toggle="modal" ng-click="openModal()">
                          Login / Signup
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Now if i am trying with following code (file locatioon is /var/www/html/views/user/mainScreen) ,but its not working,Where i am wrong ?

```
<header id="top" ng-controller="headerCtrl" roller class="navbar js-navbar-affix">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg hoj-blue-light login-reg-btn bold"
            data-toggle="modal" ng-click="openModal()">
      Login / Signup
    </button>
</header>
```

Comment: are you using angular js or angular 2+ ?

Comment: angular js (for frontend)

Comment: data-toggle attribute is for bootstrapjs and it triggers modal from that file. I suppose ur using bootstrap, in that case you have to have the modal in common place, the data-target in with id.

Answer (score 0):

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ModalCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal) {

  $scope.open = function() {
    var modalInstance =  $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: "modalContent.html",
      controller: "ModalContentCtrl",
      size: '',
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(response){
        $scope.result = `${response} button hitted`;
    });

  };
})

app.controller('ModalContentCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

  $scope.ok = function(){
    $uibModalInstance.close("Ok");
  }

  $scope.cancel = function(){
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
  } 

});
```

**modalContent.html**

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3>Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
 <h4>Just something random here</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
  <body ng-app="plunker">
    <div ng-controller="ModalCtrl">
      <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="open()" style="margin: 15px;">Open Modal</button>

      <h2 style="color: red;">{{result}}</h2>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.left-nav,.right-nav{
         float:left; 
      }
      .right-nav{
        margin-left:20px;
      }
      a{
        cursor:pointer; 
      }


.modal-header {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Example here: https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/PbnBdN

Comment: <script src="script.js"></script> put in index.html

Comment: @Anu That's what you meant?